# How can I solve error in Android studio 2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android. How can I solve this error in Android studio 2.1?

[image]

Comment: You should post error messages as text in your question, not as image.

Comment: Post the error logs displayed (click on Android Monitor tab at the bottom to see)

Comment: It looks like you have some connectivity problem to JCenter. There is very little that you can do about this, other than to determine if the connectivity problem is on your end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just import a project but never run it. What about open one of the XML file and run it?

And also, try to upgrade your Gradle to latest version, 2.1.0. It also looks like the sample code you've imported is created in previous version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out if you can reach https://jcenter.bintray.com/ from your browser.. 
jcenter usually restricts access from some IP addresses. If you cannot reach the link from your browser, you can use a VPN connection (Kerio as a better solution) and try again and then rebuild your project. As an alternative, you can change

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```

to

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

inside your project build.gradle file.